# How to upload an obfuscated MacOS app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, macos, app-store-connect, obfuscation

I have manage to build my MacOS app using : `flutter build macos --obfuscate --release --split-debug-info=/Users/foxtom/StudioProjects/MyProject/build --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=1`

And i have my app built successfully.

Now if i listen to flutter [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos), i should "Open the archive using Xcode -> Product -> Archive".
However, this operation seems to recreate a new archive and don't care about the previous command at all.

Can someone confirm that clicking on "Archive" is using the build result from the above command ? Or is it recreating a new archive from scratch ?

In any case, how can i simply submit an obfuscated macos app ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT : i have raised an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124500) because this simply doesn't seem possible unfortunately for now

Comment: If the person who vote to close could explain why this is "isn't a programming question" while there are thousands questions like this one about app store connect on SO or regarding Apple apps setup. 
If you just don't know the answer, leave it but don't vote to close since there is no where else on internet where to ask such thing, especially not Apple support regarding a Flutter thing... When we have questions regarding Flutter, the Flutter team asks us to use SO first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an ugly workaround that is actually working.
I simply create the Xcode archive, and also run the mentioned flutter command.

Once the archive is created in Xcode, i replace the content of `Products` by the one (similar) generated by Flutter.